# Load data into Bootstrap Modal from another form

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap Modal which loads by clicking a button on my jobs.php page like this here `<a class="btn default btn-block" id="jobsearch" data-toggle="modal">Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>` This then loads through this below

```
<div id="searchmodal" class="modal container fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="860" data-replace="true">
```

My jQuery is as such

```
var Search_Modal = function () {

return {
    init: function () {
        $.fn.modal.defaults.spinner = $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.spinner = 
          '<div class="page-loading page-loading-boxed">' +
              '<img src="img/loading-spinner-blue.gif" alt="" class="loading">' +
              '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...</span>'+
          '</div>';
        $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.resize = true;            
        var $modal = $('#searchmodal');
        $('#jobsearch').on('click', function(){              
          $('body').modalmanager('loading');
          setTimeout(function(){
              $modal.load('includes/jobdetailssearch.php', '', function(){
              $modal.modal();
            });
          }, 1000);
        });
        $modal.on('click', '.update', function(){
          $modal.modal('loading');
          setTimeout(function(){
            $modal
              .modal('loading')
              .find('.modal-body')                    
                .prepend('<div class="alert alert-info fade in">' +
                  'Updated!<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
                '</div>');
          }, 1000);
        });
    }
};
}();
```

The jQuery pulls a form through into the Modal, this works and looks like I want it. My issue is that I have put all the code within the form to connect to the database and return the value that is selected in the `INPUT` box on the form. Testing the form page itself returns everything it should do.

```
<?php
require '../core/cnn.php';
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchprojno'])) {
    $searchprojno = $_POST["searchprojno"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchadd'])) {
    $searchaddress = $_POST["searchaddress"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submitsearchpc'])) {
    $searchpostcode = $_POST["searchpostcode"];
}
$searchpostcode = mysql_real_escape_string($searchpostcode);
$searchaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($searchaddress);
$searchprojno = mysql_real_escape_string($searchprojno);
?>  
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Search Projects</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">    
<form class="modal-form" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchprojno" id="searchprojno" placeholder="Enter Project Number">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchprojno" name="submitsearchprojno" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchaddress" id="searchaddress" placeholder="Enter Address">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchadd" name="submitsearchadd" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" name="searchpostcode" id="searchpostcode" placeholder="Enter Postcode">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="submitsearchpc" name="submitsearchpc" >Search &nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="100px"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Address</th>
                            <th width="50px"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <?php $searchrs = mysql_query("SELECT ProjectNo, CONCAT(COALESCE(HouseNoName, ''), ' ', COALESCE(StreetName, ''), ' ', 
                            COALESCE(TownOrCity, ''), ' ', COALESCE(Postcode, '')) AS Display, PropID, AreaID, AWGMember, Householder, HouseNoName, 
                            StreetName, TownOrCity, Postcode, ContactTelephone, AlternatePhone, Email, PropertyTenure, PropertyNotes
                            FROM prop_property
                            WHERE IsActive = 1
                                AND (Postcode = '".$searchpostcode."'
                                    OR StreetName = '".$searchaddress."'
                                    OR ProjectNo = '".$searchprojno."')
                        ") or die(mysql_error());
                        $checkrs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prop_property WHERE IsActive = 0");
                        if(!mysql_num_rows($checkrs) > 0) { 
                            echo '<td> No record found!</td><td></td>'; 
                            }
                            else {
                                while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($searchrs)) {
                                echo '
                                    <td id="displayadd">'.$results['Display'].'</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="../jobdetails.php" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchhouse" value=" '.$results['HouseNoName'].'" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchstreet" value=" '.$results['StreetName'].'" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchtown" value=" '.$results['TownOrCity'].'" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchpostcode" value=" '.$results['Postcode'].'" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchpropid" value=" '.$results['PropID'].'" >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchprojectno" value=" '.$results['ProjectNo'].'" >
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn default btn-xs blue-stripe" name="viewsearch">View Address</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>';
                                }
                            }?>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer right">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

My problem is that these work as should when run as individual pages, but once put together when I put something in the `INPUT` and hit the `BUTTON` to search all that happens is that it closes the Modal and returns to the jobs.php page.

Further investigating I've come up with this after the `INPUT` is used, I've got the jQuery here, It collects the `POST` from the form as I tested it with using an alert of the `INPUT` field. I then looked at it returning the data in a table which is what I want to do. but when I look at the console log once the code runs all that happens is that it returns all the code I've written

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            //alert($('#searchpostcode').val())
            $.post('includes/jobdetailssearch.php', 
            $('#searchform').serialize(), 
            function(data, status, xhr){
                $('.table-responsive #displayadd').html(data.Display);
                console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

How can I get the form to update within the Modal and show my results in a table?